# Why 習近平 is しゅうきんぺい while 文在寅 is むんじぇいん?

Tags: readings, chinese

In broadcasts, Japanese readings of kanji are used for Chinese names while Korean readings of kanji are used for Korean names. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3013/5010

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33178/9831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly, it's because they (Korean) asked us to reflect the pronunciation. Use of kanji over katakana per se is for the sake of convenience on Japanese side.

In the background, there are their circumstances where they have been using less and less kanji and can no longer really recognize their own names through kanji.

There are even football players whose name doesn't have kanji. e.g. [차두리](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BB%8A%E3%83%89%E3%82%A5%E3%83%AA), [윤빛가람](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%B9%E3%83%93%E3%83%83%E3%82%AC%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0)